# restful call Wrong MediaType format for MediaType:"*; q=.2"

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, apache-wink

Trying to execute restful web service using POST method. Here is the relevant part of my interface:

```
@Path("/customers")
public interface CustomerResource {
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Response createCustomer(InputStream is);
        .....
}
```

The implementation:

```
 // Create customer
 public Response createCustomer(InputStream is) {
  logger.debug("In createCustomer");
  Customer customer = readCustomer(is);
  customer.setId(idCounter.incrementAndGet());
  customerDB.put(customer.getId(), customer);
  logger.debug("Created customer " + customer.getId());
  logger.debug("Out createCustomer");
  return Response.created(URI.create("/customers/"
    + customer.getId())).build();
 }
```

The client makes a call (relevant part)

```
  URL postUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ShoppingApplication/rest/customers");
  HttpURLConnection connection =
  (HttpURLConnection) postUrl.openConnection();
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
  OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
  os.write(newCustomer.getBytes());
  os.flush();
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>My Shop</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyShopping</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restfully.shop.services.ShoppingApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyShopping</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I make a call all I have back is huge exception witch is actually says:
INFO: WebApplicationException (404 - Not Found) occured during the handlers chain invocation
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:47)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:43)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:136)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:102)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:281)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jan 12, 2011 9:47:35 AM org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.header.MediaTypeHeaderDelegate fromString
SEVERE: Wrong MediaType format for MediaType:"*; q=.2"
Jan 12, 2011 9:47:35 AM org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor handleRequest
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong MediaType format for MediaType:"*; q=.2"
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.header.MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.fromString(MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.header.MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.fromString(MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.java:32)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.header.AcceptHeaderDelegate.fromString(AcceptHeaderDelegate.java:47)
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.header.AcceptHeaderDelegate.fromString(AcceptHeaderDelegate.java:32)
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf(Accept.java:139)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptHeader(HttpHeadersImpl.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptableMediaTypes(HttpHeadersImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.PopulateResponseMediaTypeHandler.handleResponse(PopulateResponseMediaTypeHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleResponse(AbstractHandler.java:38)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.ResponseHandlersChain.handle(ResponseHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.ResponseHandlersChain.handle(ResponseHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleResponse(AbstractHandler.java:39)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.ResponseHandlersChain.handle(ResponseHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.ResponseHandlersChain.handle(ResponseHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleResponse(AbstractHandler.java:39)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.ResponseHandlersChain.handle(ResponseHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.ResponseHandlersChain.handle(ResponseHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:43)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:102)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:281)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.header.MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.fromString(MediaTypeHeaderDelegate.java:54)
    ... 40 more

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it wasn't posted. I added it again.

Comment: Also please put the exception into code block, so we see special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your client code, you commented out the content type.
Why? What content type do you send?
Anyway correct media type should be `*/*;q=0.2`

Btw, what version of Wink do you use? I think the latest version is more forgivable about media types mistakes.

Comment: I uncomment it , but have the same error. The version of Wink is 0.1

Comment: First, AFAIK Wink 1.1.2 is already released. So you better upgrade. Second this sounds very strange to me. Can you put http proxy and post the result?

Comment: Guys thank you very much for your help. It is working now. The problem was with old Wink version. As soon as I uprated it to 1.1.2 it works. Thank you again my appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the jar file conflict.I deleted jetty.jar,jetty-util.jar and also deleted jsr305.jar,the REST API just work fine.
Hope this can help you.