# problem in using jersey client library in calling rest web services

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

i have a servlet which calls a rest web service using jersey client framework, here's the client code -

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
    String adCategoryId = request.getParameter("adCategoryId");
    String requirement = request.getParameter("requirement");
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource wr = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/com.pandora.services/service");
    String adResult = wr.path("search-ad").path(requirement).path(adCategoryId).get(String.class);
```

the code on the service side is this -

> @Path("/service")
>   public class Service {
>   @GET
>   @Path("/search-ad/{need}/{query}")
>   public String searchAd(@PathParam("need") String requirement,@PathParam("query") String id)
>       {
>           System.out.println("inside services");
>           String adResult = "";

```
    AdServiceProvider ad = new AdServiceProviderImpl();
    List<AdBean> adBean = ad.getAdById(Long.parseLong(id.trim()),requirement);
    adResult = gson.toJson(adBean);
    System.out.println(adResult);
    return adResult;

}
```

}

however when i make the call.. i get the following error - **Updated**

> Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletInputMessage.(HttpServletInputMessage.java:60)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:71)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createResteasyHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:197)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Jan 14, 2011 9:58:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   **SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet test threw exception
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:8080/com.pandora.services/service/hello returned a response status of 500**
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:565)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:182)
>       at com.pandora.client.servlets.test.doPost(test.java:45)
>       at com.pandora.client.servlets.test.doGet(test.java:33)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Thanks...

Comment: what params you use when making the call?

Answer (score 0):

Just two days ago the was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670491/restful-call-wrong-mediatype-format-for-mediatype-q-2?) regarding Apache Wink.

The root cause of your problem: media type in your request is incorrect. It should be `*/*` and not just `*`. The exception is very clear about that.
In the latest version of Wink, it became more forgivable about the incorrect formats of the media type. I don't know what about Jersey. But IMO it's better to fix the root problem.
My guess that the incorrect header in your case it "Accept". You can verify it using any HTTP Sniffer (e.g. Fiddler). So if you set the correct Accept header on your request, it should fix the problem.